# automatic memory release after use

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

There are lots of places that I got code like this:

```
some_function_signature() 
{
    T a;
    T b = f1(a);
    T c = f2(b);
    T d = f3(c);
    ...
}
```

As you can see, in such a function, `a` is passed to `f1()` to produce `b`, then `b` passed to `f2()` to produce `c`, and so on. These variables are not going to be used after the function call (`f1,f2,f3`...). And they hold large memory (e.g. `T` is big image data). **The problem here is that within this function, the accumulated memory consumption can be large and I'd like to reduce that. Waiting for the destructor of T to release the memory will make the peak memory usage of `some_function_signature()` very big.**

I can do something like this to free the memory after use:

```
some_function_signature() 
{
    T a;
    T b = f1(a); a.free();
    T c = f2(b); b.free();
    T d = f3(c); c.free();
    ...
}
```

I wonder if I can make this process automatic and more elegant.For example, a scoped memory management process or using sort of reference counting, but I just don't know how to best apply these methods here.

Comment: Why do you think you have to explicitly free them if you have not explicitly allocated memory for them?

Comment: `T d = f3(f2(f1(T{})));`?

Comment: @P.W The purpose is to reduce the memory consumption, whether this is explicit memory deallocation or not is another topic. And I know that does not look right and that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: The destructor should free all memory, not a magic `free` member function.

Comment: Only allocations done by malloc have to be freed. Variables allocated on stack go out of scope and are destroyed automatically.

Comment: If you are doing memory allocation (with `new` or `malloc`), you should familiarize yourself with RAII principle. If you don't do any allocation, then there's nothing to worry about here. Stack variables will be destroyed by the end of of the block.

Comment: `T b; { T a; b = f1(1); } …`?

Comment: @tkausl If all the memory get released when they are out of scope in some_function_signature(), the peak usage of this function is too big and I want to reduce that.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen please read the bold part of my question. I have clarified my point further.

Comment: @P.W please read the bold part of my question. I have clarified my point further.

Comment: @Biffen Your first suggestion should work but make code hard to read when the function call or expression is complicated. The second suggestion looks better, but how would you release b? You will end up with lots of nested {}. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a case for move semantics. Make sure that `T` and `f1/2/3` support move semantics, and change the example to

```
some_function_signature() 
{
    T a;
    T b = f1(std::move(a));
    T c = f2(std::move(b));
    T d = f3(std::move(c));
    ...
}
```

This would allow `T f1(T&& t)` to recycle the moved-in image.

Comment: ... and use the `std::unique_ptr<>` as a second choice if something refuses to move

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
T d; 
{
    T c; 
    {   
        T b; 
        {   
            T a; 
            b = f1(a); 
        } //a goes out of scope and is destroyed here 
        c = f1(b); 
    } //b goes out of scope and is destroyed here
    d = f3(c);  
}//c goes out of scope and is destroyed here
```

Comment: This is exactly what @Biffen suggested in his comments (under my question).

Comment: Okay. If move is defined for T and functions support it, that is a better approach.